# Нужно распарсить аргументы функции

Tags: javascript

Есть объект

```
const builder = {
  output: [],

  element(value) {
    return this.createSelector(value);
  },

  id(value) {
    return this.createSelector('#' + value);
  },

  class(value) {
    return this.createSelector('.' + value);
  },
  
  attr(value) {
    return this.createSelector('[' + value + ']');
  },
  
  pseudoClass(value) {
    return this.createSelector(':' + value);
  },
  
  pseudoElement(value) {
    return this.createSelector('::' + value);
  },

  combine(selector1, combinator, selector2) {
  },

  stringify() {
    const result = this.output.reduce((acc, item) => acc + item, '');
    this.output = [];
    return result;
  },

  createSelector(value) {
    const obj = new Object(this);
    this.output.push(value);
    return obj;
  }
};
```

Его метод

```
builder.combine(selector1, combinator, selector2);
```

принимает 3 аргумента. Первый и третий аргументы - это цепочки вызовов других методов объекта.

Мне нужно внутри метода builder.combine увидеть строковое представление аргументов. При попытке осуществить получаю строковое представление результатов выполнения цепочек вызова. Это, понятное дело, логично.

Уверен, должен быть способ получить именно сами цепочки вызова.

Вот, что будет входить в метод cssSelectorBuilder.combine:

```
builder.combine(builder.element('p').pseudoClass('focus'), '>', builder.element('a').attr('href$=".png"').
```

Мне надо увидеть 3 строки:

```
 - builder.element('p').pseudoClass('focus');
 - >;
 - builder.element('a').attr('href$=".png"';
```

Comment: Самое простое решение - это передать их самих как строку и внутри метода `combine` вызвать их (например с помощью `eval`)

Comment: Я не могу влиять на вызов. Это учебное задание. Я написал один из вариантов вызова, заглянув в тесты

Comment: В функцию отправляется результат выполнения. Скажите а зачем вы хотите это получить внутри `combine`? Возможно вы зря мудрите

Comment: Может быть. У меня накапливается в массиве output создаваемые селекторы. Я хотел распарсить цепочку вызовов, чтобы знать сколько селекторов из массива относить к выполнению первого аргумента, а сколько относить к выполнению третьего аргумента. Между ними надо поставить значение второго аргумента - в данном случае '>'.  Потому что в момент поступления аргументов в метод, они выполняются и заполняют массив.

Comment: Должно быть так... builder.combine(builder.element('p').pseudoClass('focus'), '>', builder.element('a').attr('href$=".png"') ).stringify() === 'p:focus > a[href$=".png"]'                                 А у меня в массиве [ 'p', ':focus', 'a', '[href$=".png"]' ]

Comment: А у вас чтобы составить селектор всегда первым делом будет вызываться `builder.element()`?

Comment: В том-то и дело, что нет. Может быть Id или Class сначала

Comment: А вам обязательно всё нужно делать в одном и том же объекте? Нельзя создать класс, а потом несколько его инстансов?

Comment: Не обязательно. Наверное, так и придётся делать. У меня изначально была такая идея, но решил попробовать так. Стандартная заготовка под решение в виде объекта была предоставлена.

Comment: Но это всё такое... Мне просто интересно, неужели нельзя посмотреть на то, что забрасывается в аргументы. Именно в исходном виде и чтобы без бубна - стандартными средствами языка. Я думал, может как-то arguments можно обработать. Если нет, то ка-то очень странно. Мне кажется, это недоработа JS. В принципе, их и так валом )

Comment: Насколько мне известно, то нельзя посмотреть. Но не считаю что это недочёт. Если даже есть, то я не знаю таких ЯП, где отправляется вызов функции и она отрабатывает не там, а уже внутри функции, куда её отправляли. Так или иначе в таких случаях  как правило - это бывает не проблема ЯП, а проблема реализации идеи :)

Comment: Может быть. Я старался избежать порождения прототипов и пытался их минимизировать. Читал, что это считается плохой практикой в наше время. За это даже критикуется фреймворк prototype.js. Моя реализация интересна и несложна. Если бы достучался до аргумента в виде строки, уже бы закончил. Ладно, буду пробовать другой вариант. Это уже был второй )). В первом варианте я вообще всё в одном объекте реализовал. 10 из 11 тестов проходил. Проблема была в последнем тесте, там уже рекурсивно забрасываются аргументы. Не глубоко - 3 вложения, именно combine в combine и это ламало мой код.